# nginx: "rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.php""

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I inherited an existing nginx+php web server running a magento dev environment, and I'm trying to figure out why it is not working.  I am able to get to the main page of the site (http://www6.MYDOMAIN.com/freesample), but any other page (such as http://www6.MYDOMAIN.com/freesample/PRODUCT-XYZ-p-1234.html) results in a "500 Internal Server Error nginx/1.10.1" in the browser, and this in the logs:

```
2017/02/07 20:43:23 [error] 30207#0: *980 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.php", client: MYIPADDRESS, server: www6.MYDOMAIN.com, request: "GET /freesample/PRODUCT-XYZ-p-1234.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www6.MYDOMAIN.com"
```

Here is my `nginx.conf`:

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  4;
error_log         /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid               /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    #brotli_static on;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request "'
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    autoindex off;
    map $scheme $fastcgi_https { ## Detect when HTTPS is used
        default off;
        https on;
    }

    keepalive_timeout  10;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/magento.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/magento.ssl.conf;

}
```

And here is the `magento.conf` that it is referencing:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www6.MYDOMAIN.com;
    #rewrite / $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent; ## Forcibly prepend a www
}

server {
    listen 80 default;
## SSL directives might go here
    server_name www6.MYDOMAIN.com; # Domain is here twice so server_name_in_redirect will favour the www
    ### root /var/www/html/freesample/;
    root /var/www/html;

    ##
    # Pagespeed main settings

    #pagespeed on;
    #pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;

    #pagespeed Statistics on;
    #pagespeed StatisticsLogging on;
    #pagespeed LogDir /var/log/pagespeed;
    #pagespeed AdminPath /pagespeed_admin;

    #location ~ ^/pagespeed_admin {
    #   allow 127.0.0.1;
    #   allow 47.23.129.108;
    #   deny all;
    #}

    # Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed
    # handler and no extraneous headers get set.

    #location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" { add_header "" ""; }
    #location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_static/" { }
    #location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon" { }

    ## end pagespeed

    ### SLI
#location ~ ^/search/go(.*)$ {
#rewrite ^/search/go(.*)$ /search$1 break;
#proxy_pass http://myspicesage.resultsdemo.com;
#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#}

#location ~ ^/search/(.*)$ {
#rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /$1 break;
#proxy_pass http://myspicesage.resultsdemo.com;
#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#}

#location ~ ^/myspicesage/(.+)$ {
#rewrite ^/myspicesage/(.+)$ /search?_raw_champ_word=$1&champ=1&view=list&sli_jump=1 break;
#proxy_pass http://myspicesage.resultsdemo.com;
#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#}

#location ~ ^/ppc/(.+)$ {
#rewrite ^/ppc/(.+)$ /search?w=$1&ppc=1 break;
#proxy_pass http://myspicesage.resultsdemo.com;
#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#}

#location ~ ^/popular$ {
#rewrite ^/popular$ /search?p=D break;
#proxy_pass http://myspicesage.resultsdemo.com;
#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#}

#location ~ ^/popular/(.+)$ {
#rewrite ^/popular/(.+)$ /search?p=D&cletter=$1 break;
#proxy_pass http://myspicesage.resultsdemo.com;
#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#}

#location ~ ^/nav/(.*)$ {
#rewrite ^/nav/(.*)$ /nav/$1 break;
#proxy_pass http://myspicesage.resultsdemo.com;
#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#}

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }
   location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

Of course you can ignore the commented lines.  I only included them to show what I've done to try and isolate what's causing the problem.

Comment: suggest reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My guess is that it's going to @handler, getting written to /index.pho, hitting the if statement, not able to find $request_filename and getting rewritten to index.php again, and then hitting the if statement again.

Comment: Is there a file at `/var/www/html/index.php`?

Comment: @RichardSmith: No, but there is a `/var/www/html/index.html`

Comment: Your configuration file is looping on trying to find a non-existent `/var/www/html/index.php`. What path do you think it should be looking for?

Comment: @RichardSmith: `http://www6.MYDOMAIN.com/freesample/PRODUCT-XYZ-p-1234.html` is what I'm trying load